# ModelBuilder being thread safe?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

This here is not really an issue but more of a question, but since I have not found anything helping on the internet and the mighty search engine of your choice, I wanted to ask that in here.

I know, that per design, EF Core was not meant to be thread safe. I totally get that point of isolation for the DbContext instances, but I was wondering, why also the model building already seems to be impacted by that.

#### Background

In order to speed up start-up time for an application, I wanted to do 2 queries in parallel, using 2 distinct DbContexts. Basically, each of them reflects a "Bounded Context Database" in my domain, one mapping to environment settings (user settings, stored UI layouts, ...) in the database and one mapping to system settings (system passwords, ...).

So when I fire up the application, I wanted to start two tasks, one going to the environment settings to fetch already the layout stuff and user settings, and one going to the system settings, to check on correct passwords etc.

#### Problem

Both tasks would create the underlying DbContext on their own, so the DbContext is created at that thread. But somehow, it seems, that the actual model-building under the hood of EF Core is done differently or not "per" thread or "per DbContext".

When I execute my application, from time to time it crashes with the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'EvaluationSettings' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
```

Having a look at my logs however reveals, that the entity was registered at the context previously.

- Thread 18 is for the system stuff and registeres SystemInformation and Variable at its context and calls "EnsureCreated"
- Thread 16 is for getting culture settings etc and registers Evaluation, EvaluationSettings, ... at the context and calls "EnsureCreated"

Afterwards, thread 16 (getting the system culture from the EvaluationSettings entity) fails.

[image]

When I do debug that issue and try to get the insights of the model-builder, I see, that only the Evaluation type is known to the DbContext model builder. The rest somehow is gone.

[image]

### Question

Could it be, that because 3 threads are calling "EnsureCreated" in parallel, only those entities get a model in the context, which were registered at that point of time?
It seems, that on that level, there is no isolation of "this model belongs to that context", right?

Anybody has a possible solution to that?
Or a suggestion how to solve that?

#### Version

EF Core 2.2.1

#### GitHub Issue

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15243

Comment: have you tried triggering the modelbuilding before, then call `EnsureCreated` and then creating your 3 dbContexts?

Comment: Yes, then it is working. But that would be the expected behavior. Question still is, why is the model building for different db-contexts itself not thread safe, as mentioned in the question? It is more out of curiosity but bug-hunting.

Problem with that solution of calling model-building first is, that I would need to have some startup-code, which knows all the used bounded contexts (and thus db contexts) afterwards and triggers the model building, which is weird upfront knowledge.

Comment: you should not be doing this anyway, since anything related to dbcontext isnt threadsafe. Of course this can be different for readonly access. But why would they implement a threadsave initialization to a non threadsave class? Does this answer your question? I may of course dig down the sources to give you a more sophisticated answer, but there is IMHO no point to it.

Comment: To me it was more a question out of interest. Why have they chosen that design? I see, that the DbContext itself is not thread-safe. But why aren't two distinct DbContexts, having a distinct set of entites not initializable in parallel? In the current world of async/await on UI level, this is quite common I would say. You have DDD in place, which favors a design on different Bounded Contexts, so you tailor your DbContexts accordingly. But then you cannot act on them independently? At least not initialize them in parallel? Why isn't the DbFacade not building and caching per DbContext?

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you mean by _two distinct DbContexts_. And yes even back in other versions of EF I've wondered why they designed it like this. And as I'm still not sure about that, I cannot answer it either. What I can tell you, is that you should rewrite, or write a new Question with a [mcve]. Post some code to make the problem reproduceable and explain why you do, what you do. But IMHO, you either accept the limits of the framework, or you use an other one.